# How to tell BeautifulSoup to ignore jsp code?

Tags: python, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm using BeautifulSoup to modify lots of both html and jsp files. These are the content files which are included to a main template. Everything works fine except that when I print out the result, BeautifulSoup deleted jsp code in the jsp files. Is there anyway to tell BeautifulSoup to ignore code between <% and %> and  tags?

Below is the code to show BeautifulSoup current behavior:

Original:

```
<tr>
  <td colspan="3"><%   if (session.getAttribute("edit")!=null){ String subid="sub-sublinks.htm";%>
    <a href="<%=subid%>"><img src="../common/images/edit2.gif" border="0"></a>  
        <%}%><jsp:include page="sub-sublinks.htm"/>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Current result:

```
<tr>
  <td colspan="3">
    <a href="&lt;%=subid%&gt;">
      <img border="0" src="../common/images/edit2.gif"/>
    </a>
    <jsp:include page="sub-sublinks.htm">
    </jsp:include>
  </td>
</tr>
```

I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for an answer to the same problem. After all research, I concluded that Beautifulsoup does not have that feature but I have come with this workaround.

First I wrap all jsp tags with another xml tag and html comments like `<ignore><!--<%some jsp code%>--></ignore>` using regular expressions. I do this with this piece of code:

```
readDocument = re.sub(r'(<%(.|\n)*?%>)',r'<ignore><!--\1--></ignore>',readDocument)
```

The reason for wrapping with html comments is that Beautifulsoup ignores the code between `<!-- -->`

The reason for wrapping with `<ignore>` tag is to find and remove html comments easily at the end of parsing.

Now you can do anything you want with 'readDocument'. After you are done with the changes you may clean extra comments with this piece of code:

```
outputText = re.sub(r'<ignore><!--|--></ignore>', r'', outputText)
```

Note: I use BeautifulSoup 3.2.0 beacuse this version does not change '<' and '>' characters to '& lt;' and '& gt;'. Newer versions may be set to not do the substitution but I am not sure about that.

Comment: After 4.10, one may use [formatter=None](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#output-formatters)